# how can i define number of tree depth in c5 model in spss modeller 18?

Tags: spss-modeler, c5

I can't inter the number of tree depth in C5 model ?!

I want to do that but I can't find the exact button. By searching I saw somewhere somebody answer that there must be gone into Build Option in C5 node, but I can't find it in the app. what should I do?